# If the size of an electron was the size of a golf ball what would the dimensions of the double slits be in a double slit experiment?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment, thought-experiment

I am thinking of the double slit experiment where single electrons were used  to produce an interference pattern. Of course I do not know what was  used as the object that the slit was in or what the definition of slit is in this particular case. Wikipedia says experiment done with 180 atoms!  Perhaps the 180 atoms are in a special "state". Lets use my golf ball instead  then what size are the "slits". And when I perform this wonderful experiment what speed should I shoot my golf ball to get an interference pattern ? Should my bulls eye be mid center between the slits?

Comment: The [classical electron radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius) is $\sim2\cdot10^{-15}$ meters; seems like you might be able to extrapolate from that, no?

Comment: Not if I don't know what size of the slit is.

Comment: You get to chose an appropriate size of the slit. There is no single required size.  Ask your teacher for help.

Comment: Can a question rightfully be tagged with both "experimental-physics" *and* "thought-experiment"?

Answer (score 3):

Your question presupposes that the electron has a "size," which is a misconception reinforced by textbooks that show electrons as little dots or blobs zipping around.
You might even have a mental picture that the electron's "size" is smaller than the nucleon's size, as if both sorts of particles were made of some "particle stuff" with the same kind of density.
But that's wrong.

The electron doesn't have an intrinsic "size" in the sense that golf balls do, where if we put a spoon less than a centimeter from the center of a golf ball we touch the golf-ball-stuff (which is mostly rubber) but if we're more than a centimeter from the center we find the vacuum. Electrons don't have this property. Or if they do, we haven't seen any evidence of it yet, because there doesn't appear to be any kind of electron-stuff. 
Electrons are fundamental, unbreakable, without internal structure at any length scale we've probed.
Either you interact with an entire electron, or you don't.

What an electron has that plays the role of "size" is a wavelength $\lambda = h/p$, which depends on the momentum of the electron in the interaction you're describing. If you want to have a golf-ball-sized electron, you need a wavelength of a centimeter or so.

To get an electron with a wavelength this huge, "all" you need to do is to cool them down until they're moving slowly enough.  I compute you'd need a kinetic energy of a few femto-eV, which means you'd need to take the eV-scale energies required to liberate electrons from atoms, and the milli-eV energies associated with room-temperature thermal motion, and cancel them out to twelve decimal places.  The closest experimental analog is probably the [ultra-cold neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutron_temperature), which typically has energy below a hundred nano-eV or so.

If you could produce these sorts of electrons, and you could get them to travel in a uniform direction (perhaps by dropping them, but note that for electrons the gravitational force is $m_e g = 50\,\text{pico-eV/meter}$) they would follow the same diffraction laws as other waves: you'd see diffraction-induced intensity minima and maxima at angles where the difference in path length between the two slits is an integer or half-integer multiple of the wavelength, with the most obvious diffraction patterns for slit separation $d\sim\lambda$.

Answer (score 2):

The wavelength that would be of interest is $\lambda = \frac{h}{mv}$ so note it depends on the speed the golf ball is going to be moving.

The slits need to be this size or smaller. There are problems producing quantum effects in large objects, though, so it is unlikely to work. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence

The 180 atoms must all be in coherent quantum states to work.

Comment: Are you saying I would need to make the slits smaller than the golf ball?  So then where would I aim ?   And the last mystery is this  :What is the definition of an object the size of a golf ball to be in a "coherent quantum state".

Comment: @Sedumjoy The thing is that particles are not balls of any kind. You will always run into problems if you imagine them as spherical objects with perfectly defined dimensions, made of solid stuff. Particles are something very different.

Comment: @mpv So buckyballs are no balls??

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I was referring mainly to elementary particles, like the electron. Buckyballs are more complicated, because they consist of multiple atoms. If you probe a buckyball to reveal its shape, you will of course find a spherical configuration of atoms. But you don't usually probe their shape during a double-slit experiment, where you need them to be in total isolation from the environment to enable the self-interference.

Comment: @mpv So they are spheres, but not if you do interferences experiments with them?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch They are quantum objects. As such they are generally in quantum superposition of states. It is difficult to explain the details in a comment, especially if you are interested in buckyballs in double-slit experiments. Feel free to post a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Any size of the slit will do.  Even an edge will do. It is just as with light: You can get interference from a double slit, from diffraction at a single slit, or from diffraction at an edge. All you need is that there are several possible paths the object (photon, golfball) can take, and there is a difference in path length between them.  And, of course, perfectly coherent golfballs (with the same momentum, i.e., wavelength).

Of course, to get the most visible fringes you want narrow slits, but in some sense this is more a "technical" problem.  Here, indeed, a conflict arises between the wavelength $\lambda=h/mv$ being very small and, at the same time, the object being very big.

Comment: Interesting , can you be a little more specific on what you mean by a conflict arising?

Comment: @Sedumjoy It's just as with light: The narrower the slits (relative to the wavelength), the better the visibility of the fringes.  Here, the slits have to be at least golfball-sized, which makes them *very* large w.r.t. the wavelength of the golfball.  The visibility will thus be very low.

Comment: what is w.r.t.?

Comment: Did you try to use a search engine? First hit on google: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/what-does-wrt-mean .  In this specific case maybe more: "as compared to"

Answer (score 0):

The double slit experiment does not easily scale up.

The purpose of the experiment is to prove the wave nature of small objects.  Regardless of which slit the object is aimed toward, when it hits the barrier containing the slits, it acts as a single wave, parts of which go through both slits simultaneously, rather than through one or the other exclusively.  Each slit then generates its own wave, and they interfere with each other.

While all objects have wavelengths, a macro object such as a golf ball contains so much more energy than an electron or than an object composed of 180 atoms (which have not lost their quantum coherence), that the golf ball must have a wave frequency much greater than the smaller objects.  The frequency of a macro-object (which has lost its quantum coherence) is so great that it will not form a recognizable interference pattern, regardless of the size of the slits.

But if you were able to maintain the quantum coherence of a golf ball, the two slit experiment would scale up, and it wouldn't matter which slit you aimed the golf balls at, or how fast they were moving.  An interference pattern would form when the object passes through both slits simultaneously.

Comment: So tell me Ernie how do I keep the quantum coherence of the golf ball? I am hell bent on seeing the this interference pattern.  If it can't be done then the point that all objects behave in a quantum manner is quite mute since in practice it can never be done.  Don't you agree?

Comment: @Sedumjoy: If a particle couples with another, or with macro objects in its environment, it is "observed" and it decoheres.  Position or momentum becomes "known" by being coupled with external degrees of freedom.  It loses its wavelike nature, and is reduced to being in one place at one time.  So far as I know, it's not possible with current technology to maintain quantum coherence in a macro object such as a golf ball.  But you can buy a cathode ray tube on eBay, dial down the intensity to single emission, aim it at a double slit barier, and witness interference on a photo film behind it.